# Best practice for `<link>` vs. `<style>` in head and in section

Tags: html, css

What is the best practice performance-wise for adding styles to sections?

```html
<style>
    .foo {
        [...]
    }
</style>
<div class="foo">
    [...]
</div>
```

or

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="foo.css">
<div class="foo">
    [...]
</div>
```

Does the best practice differ for general styles included in head vs sections?

This is different [than](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37802407/why-do-we-have-to-use-link-tag-for-css-files) [similar](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1022695/difference-between-import-and-link-in-css) [questions](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44712668/link-vs-style-for-including-css-stylesheets-with-html-documents) I could find, because I'm templating and bundling it, so it's not an issue of modularity, it's specifically about performance.

Comment: It purely depends on the size of those style blocks and how fast the user connection will be. If you are having relatively small set of styles and if it is not going to grow, its better to embed the styles inside HTML. But if you are having a quite bulky styles, better externalize it and then refer it using link href. Given all of this there are still some issues that need to be addressed in case of external stylesheet. E.g. when the FCP (First contentful paint) will happen? how the default layout and color scheme will look like when external CSS is still loading? and there is more.

Comment: so in case of critical styles I should probably put it inside and load it elsewhere to minimize the main html being loaded? Is this also true if I'm using a CDN and styles probably load way faster?

Comment: Sure you can follow that approach of embedding critical styles. But then you need to also ensure the order in which CSS style preference works. Specifically pay attention to multiple styles targeting specific elements. CDN will definitely help to load external styles faster but it also depends on internet connection speed at user end. The other option could be to show a pre-loader and load all the required resources in the background.

Comment: What do you mean by performance here? Do you mean how quickly the user sees a properly laid out page (or at least, viewport), or do you mean the overall elapsed time to load everything?

Comment: I'd like to decrease the benchmarks used by lighthouse (first contentful paint, time to interactive, total blocking time).

Comment: So, I know what each of it does, I'm asking in terms of best practice of when should I use one or the other, because I'm not familiar with browsers' particular workings when it comes to loading and rendering styles, thus I'd like to use a 'best practice' that will cover *most* cases. When deciding on a strategy I'll use in a particular project, I'll consider more things and I'll test it different ways.

Answer (score 1):

If you want for CSS to be loaded as fast as possible while still keeping it clean, *IMO* it should be done like this:

1. Keep source files in LESS/SASS format.
2. While compiling these files create minified version of it.
3. Put compiled code in CDN server or set your own server to serve compressed content
4. Any critical styles are kept in HTML file (loader animation)

Example from our site - transferred only ~300Kb while actual file is ~1.3Mb
[image]

Comment: so you basically say I should only keep the styles in the html for above the fold content and import every stylesheet into a single style.scss and load a single minified css in the head?

Comment: @zoltankundi Yes. Each Http request takes some time to load and includes time for request to travel to/from server (minimal, but still _ping_ time exists). So it's faster to zip everything into one bigger file and download it than download multiple smaller files. Also try to re-use as much CSS as possible and have slim CSS rules instead of having duplicate rules with different selectors